# Error in writing new xls file from existing xls file in matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I want to ask about how to write new xls file with the name we determine from the existing xls file. I tried this code, and it can generate new file as I want, but I can't open it as it may be corrupted. I have to use uigetfile because it would be flexible for another user to run the code. Here is my code:

```
%% Select rainfall data
% Call uigetfile by specifying file name and path as output
[filename,filepath] = uigetfile('*.xls','Select the rainfall data');        % gets directory from any folder
fido=fopen(fullfile(filepath,'rainfall.xls'),'w');                          % open output file to write
fidi=fopen(fullfile(filepath,filename));                                    % open input file
fwrite(fido,fread(fidi,'*char'));                                           % copy to output
fclose(fidi);                                                               % close that input file
fido=fclose(fido); clear fid*
```

It can generate rainfall.xls, but when I open the file through excel, the content is in a mess (attached picture). I also attach the existing xls file. What I want to do actually to copy the existing file into rainfall.xls, then I can impor the rainfall.xls into a table in matlab. I want to integrate it to this code that I generate it through import tools:

```
[![%% Import data from spreadsheet
% Script for importing data from the following spreadsheet:
%
%    Workbook: D:\TUM\Study Project\Study Project TUM\raw data\rain gauge\ULL00317_20171102.xls
%    Worksheet: Tabelle1
%
% To extend the code for use with different selected data or a different
% spreadsheet, generate a function instead of a script.
% Auto-generated by MATLAB on 2017/11/03 19:36:55
%% Import the data, extracting spreadsheet dates in Excel serial date format
\[~, ~, raw, dates\] = xlsread('D:\TUM\Study Project\Study Project TUM\raw data\rain gauge\ULL00317_20171102.xls','Tabelle1','A:F','',@convertSpreadsheetExcelDates);
raw(cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(x) && isnumeric(x) && isnan(x),raw)) = {''};
raw = raw(:,\[2,3,4,5,6\]);
dates = dates(:,1);
%% Replace non-numeric cells with NaN
R = cellfun(@(x) ~isnumeric(x) && ~islogical(x),raw); % Find non-numeric cells
raw(R) = {NaN}; % Replace non-numeric cells
R = cellfun(@(x) ~isnumeric(x) && ~islogical(x),dates); % Find non-numeric cells
dates(R) = {NaN}; % Replace non-numeric Excel dates with NaN
%% Create output variable
data = reshape(\[raw{:}\],size(raw));
%% Create table
ULL0031720171102 = table;
%% Allocate imported array to column variable names
ULL0031720171102.DatumUhrzeit = datetime(\[dates{:,1}\].', 'ConvertFrom', 'Excel');
ULL0031720171102.ULL00317_3 = data(:,1);
ULL0031720171102.ULL00317_CH31 = data(:,2);
ULL0031720171102.ULL00317_CH32 = data(:,3);
ULL0031720171102.ULL00317_1 = data(:,4);
ULL0031720171102.ULL00317_2 = data(:,5);
% For code requiring serial dates (datenum) instead of datetime, uncomment
% the following line(s) below to return the imported dates as datenum(s).
% ULL0031720171102.DatumUhrzeit=datenum(ULL0031720171102.DatumUhrzeit);
%% Clear temporary variables
clearvars data raw dates R;
```

Could you please help me? Thank you very much for your help.

This is the exiting xls file:
[image: Existing xls file]

This is the new xls file which is in a mess:
[image: new xls file]

Comment: The same question over and over with no efforts to get things working. Just look at the profile activity of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

`fread` reads binary files (the mess that you see) which you end up rewriting, use `xlsread` instead to read tabular files.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is copying 1 file to another without changing anything then just use `copyfile`.

```
copyfile(fullfile(filepath,filename),fullfile(filepath,'rainfall.xls'))
```

Then you can use your other exisiting code to read and format he data.  All you have to do is swap the filename with `fullfile(filepath,'rainfall.xls')`